# is there a way to limit firebase hosting downloads for a specific custom demain?

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

We are in Flame plan on firebase and we are hosting many custom domains, so yesterday we noticed a sudden raise on a specific domain download (25Go ! in normal days it's 2Go maximum), so is there a way to limit specific domain downloads on firebase? and if we pass the limit of the Flame plan what are the consequences? thanks

Comment: You can use https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/reference/rest/v1beta1/sites.versions/delete to delete a version of your site programmatically. Though I am unsure if there is any way to 'undeploy' a site. Also, firebase now offers only two plans: Spark (free) & Blaze.

Comment: thank you for your comment, we are on Flame plan before Firebase updates their plans, so they didn't change our offer. We know that we can use their api to delete a domain but this is not what I asked for, we only want to limit a specific domain downloads.